# setContentView error

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I created new layout named splash.xml like below and put in in layout folder.
[image]
Then I create a class named Splash.java like below

```
   package com.example.buttonproj;
    import android.R;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;


    public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash); //ERROR HERE

    }

}
```

There is an error on `setContentView(R.layout.splash)`. Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Do that and post the XML file if errors persist.

Comment: sometimes eclipse refuseses to recognize your R. Try the full package name - com.example.nuttonproj.R.layout.splash

Comment: I clean and refresh the project but it didnt work. The XML file is in the image above.

Comment: @mihail you are right. it worked. so strange. but thanks.

Comment: check Sam's answer. This is the reason why it is happening.

Answer (score 14):

Remove the line:

```
import android.R;
```

and verify that your XML files don't have any errors.

Eclipse sometimes imports this when a resource file has a compilation error and you automatically update your dependents (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> for example).  Eclipse then tries to read the wrong R file which wreaks creates havoc *everywhere* you reference `R.*`

Find the root cause (in the Package Explorer window, look for any files in your `res/` folder with the red *x*) and clean your project (Project -> Clean).

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing the

```
import android.R;
```

and try importing the R from your project.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers.

I summarized the answer as below:

1. sometimes eclipse refuseses to recognize your R. Try the full package name - com.example.nuttonproj.R.layout.splash – mihail

OR

1. removing the

import android.R;

Comment: If you do not import any other `R` files (especially not `android.R`), you should never need to use the full path to reference your `R` file.  This is the benefit / purpose of importing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be in the layout background: @drawable/abc. Does it exist in the drawable(s) folders?

Answer (score 0):

1. Never import **android.R;** it will include the system R components rather than user defined.